# SwiftUI List onDelete IndexSet to int

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I convert the offesets: IndexSet value to just a plain int?

I can get a range using offsets.startIndex, but that still doesn't give me an int. startIndex seems to be the value I need to pass to the view model, so that I can update the underlying array.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562459/12299030?

Comment: Yep, that's done it, thank you... I don't know why they're not using the good ole IndexPath.row any more...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the index of a deleted row from a list in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61562137/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-deleted-row-from-a-list-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through IndexSet to get the specific index of the array which user trigger to delete.

```
        .onDelete {indexSet in
            for index in indexSet{
                print(index)
            }
        }
```

There will be only one element **index** which will be index of array getting deleted.